# Best approach for energy demand forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, supervised-learning, perceptron

I am trying to predict the amount of energy demand(Wh) of the next two weeks per hour. The dataset I have, contains each hour of each day since 2019 of the energy demand, is something like this:

```
X = [[[day],[month],[year],[hour],[consumption]],
      [[05], [01],  [2018],[10],  [150000]],
      [[05], [01,   [2018],[11],  [153000]],
      ...till today]
```

The thing is that I have fed this dataset (after preprocessing) to a MLP(dense fully connected layers) and it seem to give good results in the validation set, but this validation set is formed by a sample of the X dataset, so it is likely that the training set has the information of the demand of the hour before and after of every one in the validation set, which would be something like cheating since from one hour to next one there are little changes in demand, and because the real case is that I would like to have a model which can predict one/two weeks further in time the energy demand per hour.
I have thought that maybe there is a kind of way to fit a model only using, when predicting a given hour' demand, the subset of the training set that is two weeks or more before on time that the given hour. This is what I have thought but I don't know if it is possible or if there are other approaches better than this one. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the time series instead of using a subsample as a test set, to avoid the problem you mentioned. You can find more here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/205266/wind.

Also regarding your problem, I think the energy demand has cyclic features. I suggest you take a look at the book *"Introduction to Machine Learning with Python"* by Andreas C. Müller and Sarah Guido (ed. O'Reilly). Look for Figure 4-12 *"Number of bike rentals over time for a selected Citi Bike station"* and the text there, I think they solve in a nice way the very same problem you are trying to solve.

**EDIT:** Following the comments, I add this update.

First, I don't think this is a general problem, so MLP is not too relevant in the discussion actually.  Also, I assume here that you are familiar with cross-validation. What I understand about the procedure depicted in that graph is this. A way to do train the model is to keep let's say the last 3 months as a test set, and the previous data as training (after the split, the last part of the data always as test, of course, since you want to predict the future knowing the past). However, only with that you would compute a single value for you model accuracy. To do it better, you can do cross-validation in which case you split the same data in a different ways, with new training and test sets. That would give you different values for the accuracy. Proceeding in this way, you can average many values of accuracy to get a better, more robust and significant estimate of how you model performs, for the set of parameters you use (I assume you model has some free parameters that you can tune).

What is specific about time series is that the partition between training and test set only makes sense if the test set is, in time, after the training data, since as I said before you want to predict the future based on the past. Thus, if you have, for the sake of the argument, some time index t=1,2,3,.....100 you can use first a training set t=1-90 and a test t=91-100. Then, you repeat, this time with a training set t=1-80 and a test t=81-90 etc. until training t=1-10 and test t=11-19.

Regarding this question "Because that is too much data for training in comparison with the data you are predictiong": if your problem is that you cannot afford to do cross-validation, ok it's not mandatory, it's just desirable. However, if your problem is that you have so many training data that you cannot possibly train the model due to computational limitations, then you can indeed sub-sample your data to reduce it. For example, make time bins an average the values in each bin. Or simply remove 1h from every 2h (just try not to systematically remove the most meaningful hours! This is something you can also play with, since some sub-samplings can work while others can ruin the model performance). Then, from the sub-sampled data, you can create the test set as described above. Also, you should perform the same sub-sampling operation on future data you are given before making a prediction (well, you can check how your model behaves, but probably you will have to).

Comment: That book explains this topic so good, thank you a lot. What I don't fully understand is the post you can find on the link you left. That is, I don't know how you can build a MLP model with the past data in order to predict, for instance just the next two weeks. Because that is too much data for training in comparison with the data you are predictiong. How do you know you aren't overfitting? Maybe creating some pairs (training, test) and using some of them as validation data?

Comment: To sum up, I don't understand the graph in that post

Comment: see the update. I don't focus on MLP because I think the issue here is not specific to MLP.

Comment: That answered all my questions. What I didn't understand was why CV was performed. I realise that this is just to know if your model is doing well or not. And after you choose the best model, you take all the data to predict the future. Thank you @kastellane!

Comment: Yes, because the accuracy is a random variable that depends on the sample on which you train and test the model. By doing cross-validation, you compute an average accuracy which is more reliable (you get the most out of your available data). I'm glad it helped. I you liked it, remember to mark the answer as best answer with the check mark on the left. Cheers.

Comment: P.S.: everything regarding CV is on the book I referred to above.

Comment: I don't want to look like annoying, but I prefer to ask rather than leaving something that I don't understand. I got everything you've said. But what happens after you choose the best model parameters using CV? I mean, how do you train this time the model with all the data in order to predict the new one(future data)? Because I don't imagine what should be the target data and the training data for the final model in order it has good performance in new data.

Comment: No problem. You must leave one piece of data out of the cross-validation. Thus, you actually consider 3 sets. Training, validation sets and test (see in the book I referred to). The test set is not used during the CV.  During CV you are splitting the data (leaving aside the test data) into training and validation sets. With that you decide on which parameters are the best. Then, you can asses the optimized model on the never-seen test data.

Comment: The test data looks to your model just as any new data you might receive in the future. In this way you can get an idea of how the model would perform with future data that you haven't seen yet (as long as it is similar to the test data).

Comment: So, to end with your masterclass and my lack of knowledge, imagine the best model to predict tomorrow's target is the one that end up with  training set t=1-80 and val set t=81-90. You mean that I should take that model, find the best parameters using CV in the training set  t=1-80 and val set t=81-90 and then check for  the test set, if I got you. But if the new data(future data) is in the range, suppose t =121-130, how can the model trained on the training set t=1-80 be good to predict such new elements? I am sorry, because I got you, but there is something I am not fully understanding.

Comment: The best model to predict tomorrow's target is defined by the value of the tuned parameters, not by any of the cross-validation sets as the set t=1-80 or any other. I mean that you set a combination of free parameters, then train the model on all the sets  t=1-10,  t=11-20 etc... That way you can obtain an average accuracy for that combination of free parameters. Then you try different combinations of free parameters, always computing the average accuracy. At the end, you keep the combination with best average accuracy.

Comment: Then, with that optimum combination, you re-train using all the data, except for the test set. After this final training, you evaluate on the test set. This few steps are explained in many places, look for this keywords: cross-validation and grid search. You will find so many videos. The only specific thing to your problem is how you split the data for cross-validation since you are using time series.

Comment: okay I finally got it. Thanks for your patience!